# Zygote preloading vs boot.art loading

Tags: android, android-source, android-runtime

## Boot images loading (boot.oat, boot.art)

When Android boots up, it loads some `boot images` which contain some frequently used classes. In particular `boot.oat` contains the code of the classes, and `boot.art` some pre-initialized heap.
This speedups application launch, and saves some memory due to the paging mechanism. (More details [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/configure.html))

## Zygote preloading

In ZygoteInit.java, there is a [preload](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/os/ZygoteInit.java#180) function.
It preloads classes, resources, shared libraries, etc.
`preloadClasses` in particular loads the classes found in:
`/system/etc/preloaded-classes`. Which basically causes the static initializers of these classes run.

## How they differ?

What is the difference between the two?
Isn't the sole purpose of `boot.art` to avoid the explicit initialization that is done by zygote`s`preload`?

Shouldn't the zygote's `preload` run only for `imageless` bootup?

Answer (score 4):

What is the difference between the two? Isn't the sole purpose of `boot.art` to avoid the explicit initialization that is done by zygote's preload`?

`boot.art` is a oat file. It contains all the classes in `BOOTCLASSLOADER`. Oat is a special `elf` format. It's a necessary file in ART VM. It will be generated at first boot or integrated in the phone by manufacturer.

`/system/etc/preloaded-classes` is a file contains a list of classes that will be initialized in the `zygote`.

Shouldn't the zygote's preload run only for imageless bootup?

`boot.art` is not an image.

`boot.art` is a special oat file. It contains all the class definitions of jars (`framework.jar` etc.) in `BOOTCLASSLOADER` and is in the memory of every application. Android converts these jar files to oat file to support the ART VM. Loading `boot.art` will load all the class definitions in  `boot.art` into the memory of the zygote process. The classes are **not** initialized by ClassLoader after loading into memory and they are usually initialized when first used. 

Some classes in `boot.art` are used in almost every application so we can initialize them in zygote to avoid initializing them in every application.  Preload will call the `Class.forName` method to initialize the classes in `/system/etc/preloaded-classes`. `Class.forName` initializes the static block in target class and does other initialization operations. The result of preload is actually memory change and the change remains in the forked processes. So preload will save class initialization time.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because /system/etc/preloaded-classes wasn't really part of boot.art. Android provides the flexibility to choose what goes into boot.art so that the image size can be kept small but which obviously will result into a few classes being loaded at run time during zygote initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Preloaded-classes file is simply a [text file](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/config/preloaded-classes), it lists the class names to be loaded by Zygote. Zygote based on this list to load all the Android Java frameworks, it uses Classs.forName() to load the Java classes.
`boot.art` is the image file of the classes, so the actual classes are here. ART runtime just takes in charge of loading this file into process memory by memory mapping technology. There is no Java class loading here.